# Save loop output into a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a loop to get a list of terms for a taxonomy.

```
    <?php 
  $terms = get_field('modell');
  if( $terms ):
    $total = count($terms);
    $count = 1;
    foreach( $terms as $term ):
      ?>
      '<?php echo $term->slug; ?>'
      <?php 
      if ($count < $total) {
        echo ', ';
      }
      $count++;
    endforeach;
  endif; 
?>
```

The loop output is this:

```
 'termname-one','termname-two','termname-three'
```

Now I want to save this output into variable (**$termoutput**)  and insert it into a array of terms of following loop:

```
<?php 
query_posts( array(  
    'post_type' => 'posttypename', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array( 
       array( 
          'taxonomy' => 'systems', 
          'field' => 'slug', 
         'terms' => array($termoutput)
       ) 
   ) 

) );    ?>
```

Is there a way to achive this? Thank you!

Comment: `$termoutput = [];` before the foreach. Then in your loop instead of echo use `$termoutput[] = $term->slug;`... that's literally it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accumulate your output into an array like this:

```
$termoutput = array();

...

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $termoutput[] = $term->slug;
}
```

Then, in the second section of your code:

```
...
'terms' => $termoutput
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <?php 
  $terms = get_field('modell');
  if( $terms ):
    $total = count($terms);
    $count = 1;
    $termoutput = array();
    foreach( $terms as $term ):

      echo "'".$term->slug."'"; 
      $termoutput[] = $term->slug;

      if ($count < $total) {
        echo ', ';
      }
      $count++;
    endforeach;
  endif; 
?>


<?php 
    query_posts( array(  
        'post_type' => 'posttypename', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array( 
          array( 
              'taxonomy' => 'systems', 
              'field' => 'slug', 
             'terms' => $termoutput
           ) 
       ) 

    ) );    
 ?>
```

This will store **$term->slug** to **$termoutput[]** as an array.

Comment: This will throw a warning in some cases because you haven't preset `$termoutput` as an array before the loop. Add `$termoutput = array();` before the foreach.

Comment: @naththedeveloper sorry forgot about that, was busy editing his code. Thank you