# WP ACF relationship query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In my "Cases" post type, I have a ACF relationship field called "Work" where I connect "Cases" with the post type "Work". One of the posts in "Work" is called "Branding".

This is where I'm at right now:

```
$case_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'cases', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_key'      => 'work',
    'meta_value'    => 'branding',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
 );
    
$cases = new WP_Query( $case_args );    

if( $cases->have_posts() ): while( $cases->have_posts() ) : $cases->the_post(); ?>
```

The code return.. nothing.

What I'm expecting is to return all posts of the post type "Cases" which has a relationship with "Branding".

Anyone who has a clue of what's wrong with the code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are actually trying to display data. Why bother with `if ($cases->have_posts())` if you are going to call `while()`?  It seems to me that the `if` condition can be safely omitted.  Have you isolated which part of `$case_args` is failing to produce results?  Did you trying systematically altering/removing elements from that array until some data was actually returned?  We can't see your database, so it is hard for us to help you.  Please never include "thanks in advance" in any question.

Comment: Do you actually want to store `the_post()` data to some sort of result array?  `$result = []; while($cases->have_posts()) { $result[] = $cases->the_post(); } var_export($result);`  If this is the solution, then we can safely close this question as a facepalm/typo question because it is not likely to help future researchers.  Or maybe a duplicate of [Save loop output into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46809841/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved my problem by changing my array to:

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'cases',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'work',
           'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
     )
)
```

Thanks for your suggestions!